# PHP/MySQL Insert into Database not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I tried everything I could to fix the link of code but everything I tried gave me a white screen I know that this line of code is the only code is the only one that has a syntax error and the rest of the code is 100% fine. I am trying to insert name, email, password from a Form using $_POST and with md5 hashing for the password.

$link = connect to mySQL Database

```
$query="INSERT INTO 'users' ('name', 'email', 'password')
VALUES(
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name'])"',
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."',
 '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password'])."')";
```

Comment: `md5()` is not safe.

Comment: a start would be `hash('sha512', $password)` but even better would be http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php. Ofcourse you could somehow use `md5()` to hash the password before going trough one of the others

Comment: You don't quote column/table names, those should be backticks. `INSERT INTO \`users\` (\`name\`, \`email\`, \`password\`)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: Serious SQL Injection vulnerability here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071)

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm missing the injection hole here I think, what is it?

Comment: Any time you construct a SQL query from user-provided strings you run a risk of SQL injection (no matter how well you supposedly "clean up" the strings).  This is 100% avoidable using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @JimGarrison do you know we could use prepared statements in this strip of code?

Comment: I've posted a prepared example. I don't use `mysqli` i've always used `PDO` with prepared statements so thanks for the note on `mysqli_real_escape` being vulnerable @JimGarrison.

Comment: @JimGarrison even prepared statements aren't a 100% safe. There is even a stackoverflow post about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you make it simple instead? Something like:

```
$name  =   mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']);
$mail  =   mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
$pass  =   md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password']);

$query="INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES('$name','$mail', '$pass')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a dot:

```
$query="INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) 
        VALUES('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']) . "', '" . md5(md5($_POST['email']) . $_POST['password']) . "')";
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/sites/testdomain.io/html/index.php on line 30

Answer (score 0):

```
query="INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`)
    VALUES(
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name'])"',
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."',
     '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password'])."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
$password = hash('sha512', md5( md5( $_POST['email'] ).$_POST['password'] ) );

$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES('$name','$email', '$password')";
```

Note the backticks around table and column names. Also note the difference in echoing the following:

```
echo 'hashed: '.hash('sha512', md5( md5( $_POST['email'] ).$_POST['password'] ) ).'<br>md5(): '.md5( md5( $_POST['email'] ).$_POST['password'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of VALUES() you've missed a point.

Incorrect:

```
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name'])"',
```

Correct:

```
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name'])."',
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough (untested) sample of how your statement could look as a prepared statement.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 
"INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password']));
//mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); //<--to execute query, use where you execute
```

Here's the manual's reference on it, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php.